# Why did Constantine take the amulet from the priest?

Tags: dc, constantine-2005, constantine

In the movie [Constantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_%28film%29) said, "You don't need its protection, it would be like the old days."

Did the amulet prohibit hearing voices? So he could find out what's happening and report back to Constantine or something else?

Comment: Great Question. I always wondered about that myself, because the only explanation I have ("He wanted it for himself") doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: Ahh.. you are actually asking a question with the quote wrong! it is "You don't need HIS protection"... Make a lot more sence now, dont it? :)

Comment: @WizardOz : "His", who is he? It makes even less sense now! I check it again, this has been bugging since the movie came out!

Comment: @WizardOz : according to http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/c/constantine-script-transcript-keanu-reeves.html : Come on, you don't need its protection. It'll be like back in the day.  That seems to suggest he just needed it and was going to give it back asap. But the poor priest didn't last that long.

Comment: Since the main plot was loosely based on the "Dangerous Habits" story arc (Hellblazer #41–46), maybe the comic has some clues?

Comment: I thought it was because the priest would be able to fend off for himself for a while (even though the amulet would provide much more protection).

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: @MartinSchröder : The movie, "Constantine", he took the protective amulet from the priest at the beginning of the movie. After the priest failed the exorcism.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While neither the movie or the script specifically discuss what powers the amulet possesses or grants, John gives it to Angela as a ward of sorts. From [the script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Constantine.html):

> ```
> John turns to her -- locks on those eyes. He reaches
> into his coat pocket as he walks up to her. She shudders
> as his arms wrap around her face and for a beat they're
> cheek to cheek. When he pulls back she sees he has
> clipped Hennessey's AMULET around her neck.
>
>                       JOHN
>
>        Think of it as a bulletproof vest.
> ```

Here is where the script and the movie diverge.

In the movie, Angela accidentally leaves the amulet in the car when she takes off her jacket and it's when John notices the missing amulet that Angela is abducted.

So, added to John's earlier comment to Hennessey, it's reasonable to assume that it provides protection from attacks by demons/half-breeds.

As for exactly why he took - or, as in the script, removed the amulet - let's look at the script again.

> ```
>                     HENNESSEY
>
>          Oh God, you want me to surf the
>          ether.
>
>        He instinctively touches an AMULET around his neck.
>        Four intersecting crosses.
>
>                        JOHN
>
>          Come on, you know that exorcism
>          wasn't right.
>
>                        HENNESSEY
>
>          I... I don't have the Sight
>          anymore.
>
>                        JOHN
>
>          Don't have it or don't want to use
>          it?
>
>          Hennessey vacillates.
>          This is obviously tough for him.
>
>                        JOHN
>
>          Just look around. A few days.
>          You spot anything unusual,
>          anything -- you let me know.
>          Okay?
>
>          John wraps an arm around his shoulder like a good buddy,
>          then reaches behind his neck --
>
>                        JOHN
>
>          It'll be like old times.
>         -- and unclips the amulet from Hennessey's neck. That
>         unnerves the big guy. John drops it in Hennessey's
>        pocket.
>
>                        JOHN
>
>          Just for a few days.
> ```

This backs up the idea that the amulet is a ward. By removing it, John hopes that Demons may come closer to Hennessey and he may be able to learn something.

Finally, we have the script version of the scene where John and Angela find Hennessey in the store.

> ```
> John leans down to the remains of his friend. A cop starts to
> intervene but Angela blocks him. Let him be. John has trouble taking
> this in, reluctantly reaches into Hennessey's coat pocket -- finds the
> protective amulet he himself removed from his friend. That's even more
> crushing.
> ```

This final bit pretty much confirms (IMO, at least) that the amulet was meant to protect the wearer from demon attacks.

Comment: Occam's Razor suggests that the amulet prevents perception of the supernatural and nothing more. A seer who wears it can't See, so John took it off Hennessey. The demon who killed Hennessey did so without laying a finger on him -- and perhaps therefore without breaking the rules -- by using illusions. Hennessey had worn it, not just to prevent that kind of attack, but to spare himself what he would otherwise glimpse now and then. And in the film, when John puts it on Angela, it's a precaution. (According to this theory, it wouldn't have prevented her abduction.)

Comment: If it was only to mask perception, John wouldn't have explained it as "a bulletproof vest" to Angela.

Comment: There's a brief scene where Hennessey is rifling through tons of grim articles and eventually seizes on the story of Angela's sister.  I'd guess that gain of insight is the explicit reason for taking off his "vest".

Comment: It is also part of a general trope (can't remember the TV Tropes title) that being able to see extradimensional beings often means they will notice you noticing and can then affect you.

Answer (score 2):

"His" protection in the whole movie (unless there is a back story to it) refers to God. Constantine displays this rebellious attitude the whole time, even as he was going to heaven for sacrificing his own life (he was showing the middle finger to Lucifer). The priest was psychic and such ability comes with a price. While the priest was holy enough he in normal terms would be open to demonic attack and makes him susceptible to being possessed or damaged in some way. Thus the amulet prevents such dark forces to intercept in between. However, in order to use that power he has to take off the amulet so that he is "open" to his normal "channels". Sort of like taking lithium for schizophrenics who hear things. This is spiritual lithium.

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely worn to ward off demons. As for  John taking it off the priest, he didn't take it for himself.,he put in the priests pocket .Only when he needed it for Angela did he take it. I'm sure it was meant to help find the demons by drawing them closer .I believe this based on the movie. Could be wrong though....  Awesome movie I've probably seen upwards of a hundred times and I'll keep watching I love it. Oh as for it keeping the voices out ,it didn't.,the drinking did.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. However, I'm not clear on what your actual explanation is for _why_ Constantine took the amulet from the priest. What did he mean to achieve by that? Also, when you say that you believe -- based on the movie -- that the amulet was meant to help find the demons by drawing them closer, can you be a bit more specific about what _precisely_ leads you to that conclusion? Is it something in the dialogue? If so, it would help if you edited your answer to include the relevant quote/s.

Answer (score 0):

The amulet merely acts as a buffer or blindfold for those with the gift of sight or those that are tuned into the underworld. The priest was a medium that possessed a very strongly-tuned spirit antenna. He not only wore the amulet but also attempted to dull his sixth sense (along with others) with copious amounts of alcohol.

John removes the amulet from the spirit-tuning-fork priest so that he could dial-in the happenings he no longer had access to. John had to do life-threatening acts to bring him close to death, which allowed him a peek into the spirit world.  He gives the amulet to Ana so that she could be spared from the visions that were becoming stronger for her as she was an inexperienced tuning fork and John believed that ignorance would be bliss for her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to include any relevant evidence (such as quotes) to corroborate what you've said here.

Answer (score -1):

It was definitely worn to ward off demons. As for  John taking it off the priest, he didn't take it for himself.,he put in the priests pocket .Only when he needed it for Angela did he take it. I'm sure it was meant to help find the demons by drawing them closer .

Comment: If you want to amend one of your answers, you should click on the 'edit' button beneath that answer to edit it, rather than using the 'Your Answer' box to post the amended version as a second answer to the same question.